# Angular loop is not updating

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-http

Just started out with angular. I was successful in saving and retrieving the data from a DB with php. I am also able to loop the data within a list item but when i add a new user the list does not update only when i refresh the browser does it show the newly added user

this is my html code:

```
<div>
    <ul ng-init="get_user()">
        <li ng-repeat="user in userInfo ">{{user.user_name}}<a href="" ng-click="prod_delete(product.id)"> --> Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is my app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('AddUser', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.userInfo =  [];

    /** function to add details for a user in mysql referecing php **/
    $scope.save_user = function() {

        $http.post('db.php?action=add_user', 
            {
                'user_name'  : $scope.user_name, 
                'user_email' : $scope.user_email
            }
        )

        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.userInfo.push(data);
            console.log("The user has been added successfully to the DB");
            console.log(data);
        })

        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Failed to add the user to DB");
        });
    }

    /** function to get info of user added in mysql referencing php **/
    $scope.get_user = function() {
        $http.get('db.php?action=get_user').success(function(data)
        {
            $scope.userInfo = data;   
            console.log("You were succesfull in show user info"); 
            //console.log(data);
        })
    }

    });
```

Comment: you should call the `$scope.get_user()` method to fetch data from DB again

Comment: OP as parkar said  it should be done as ng-init is called only once.

Comment: but GY22 is pushing `data` into `userInfo` in success of $http.post

Comment: What is `data` exactly?

Comment: yeah i got it data could be  wrong sorry.

Comment: @A.J it really a questionable thing..does he returned saved data from server..doing server call is more preferred way of doing it

Comment: @pankajparkar totally agree with you.

Comment: @GY22 should I add an answer?

Comment: @pankajparkar, no not necessary i guess

Comment: @GY22 I asked because that could help other..if you don;t want then its fine :p

Comment: @pankajparkar, ok add an answer then i can tick it as resolved and you are right it will help others

Comment: @GY22 I added an answer..do look at it accept answer.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing post call which is saving data to DB through server method, but in you success of post call you are pushing that data in `userInfo` object which technically sounds wrong.

I'd prefer you to make an ajax to get new data from db using `$scope.get_user()` after post call gets succeed.

**Code**

```
$scope.save_user = function() {
    $http.post('db.php?action=add_user', {
       'user_name'  : $scope.user_name, 
       'user_email' : $scope.user_email
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       //$scope.userInfo.push(data); //remove this line
        $scope.get_user(); //this will fetch latest record from DB
        console.log("The user has been added successfully to the DB");
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Failed to add the user to DB");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing save user to this:

```
$scope.save_user = function() {
    $http.post('db.php?action=add_user', {
        'user_name'  : $scope.user_name, 
        'user_email' : $scope.user_email
    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.userInfo.push(data.data);
        console.log("The user has been added successfully to the DB");
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Failed to add the user to DB");
    });
}
```

I think your data that you are returning is an object and whatever data you are expecting would be data.data, so you are pushing an invalid object to your userInfo array

Comment: I'd suggest pushing the added user name and email from the http response to make sure things are added correctly, in case you have some param name typo and actually saved blank in some fields.

Comment: Updated, I think the problem is that the data is returned under data.data so the keys that the loop is looking for don't exist on the object he is pushing