# Angular does not updated loop due to implementation $mdDialog (Material Design)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

Based on my previous post: [Angular loop is not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033371/angular-loop-is-not-updating), i updated the code slightly to add a dialog box to the button a a user.

the only change in my app.js file is the directive to add a $mdDialog box. so the complete code for my app.js file is:

```
var app = angular.module('AddUser', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $mdDialog){
$scope.userInfo =  [];

/** function to add details for a user in mysql referecing php **/
$scope.save_user = function() {
    $http.post('db.php?action=add_user', 
        {
            'user_name'  : $scope.user_name, 
            'user_email' : $scope.user_email
        }
    )

    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.userInfo.push(data);
        $scope.get_user(); //this will fetch latest record from DB
        console.log("The user has been added successfully to the DB");
        console.log(data);
    })

    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Failed to add the user to DB");
    });
}

/** function to get info of user added in mysql referencing php **/
$scope.get_user = function() {
    $http.get('db.php?action=get_user').success(function(data)
    { 
        $scope.userInfo = data;   
        console.log("You were succesfull in showing user info"); 
        //$scope.get_user(); //this will fetch latest record from DB
    })
}

/** function to delete a user from list referencing php **/
$scope.delete_user = function(index) {  
    $http.post('db.php?action=delete_user', 
        {
            'user_index' : index
        }
    )      
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {    
        $scope.get_user();//this will fetch latest record from DB
        console.log('Deletion was succesfull');
    })

    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log("You were NOT succesfull in deleting a user"); 
    });
}

$scope.showPopUp= function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'popup.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
    })
};

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    }

    $scope.save_user = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    }
}

});
```

i had to comment out the following code in the get_user function ($scope.get_user();) otherwise i could not preform a delete but then on the other hand the loop did not update. so either i comment out $scope.get_user() in de get_user function and then i can delete a user or i don't comment it out and the loop will update when i add a new user but then the delete function does not work ...

my html code is:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div>
    <ul ng-init="get_user()">
      <li ng-repeat="user in userInfo ">{{user.user_name}}<a href="#" ng- 
      click="delete_user(user.id)"> --> Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

 <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showPopUp($event)" flex 
 flex-md="100">Add a user</md-button>
</body>
```

and the code for the dialog box (popup.tmpl.html) is the following:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Add or invite a user" ng-app="AddUser">
<form ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <md-toolbar>
       <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
         <h2>Add or invite a user</h2>
         <span flex></span>
         <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="closeDialog()">
              <md-icon md-svg-src="images/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close 
              dialog"></md-icon>
         </md-button>
       </div>
      </md-toolbar>
      <md-dialog-content>
        <div>
          <div layout="" layout-sm="column">
            <md-input-container flex="">
            <label>Enter a name</label>
            <input name="user_email" ng-model="user_name">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div layout="" layout-sm="column">
          <md-input-container flex="">
          <label>Enter an e-mail</label>
          <input name="user_name" ng-model="user_email">
          </md-input-container>
       </div>
      </div>
     </md-dial
     <div class="md-actions" layout="row">
       <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">Cancel</md-     
        button>
       <md-button ng-click="save_user()" name="add_user" class="md-
       primary">Add</md-button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </md-dialog>
```

Comment: could you create a plunkr so that the we can give some help..

Comment: @pankajparkar, you won't see that much if i put it on plunkr (its with a db and php) -> http://plnkr.co/edit/sFo34cF9DWK3TzFpzmQD?p=preview

Comment: i dont understand where is you problem. Please explain more what is not working with your actual code.

Comment: @MilosMosovsky, i had to comment out the following code in the get_user function ($scope.get_user();) otherwise i could not preform a delete but then on the other hand the loop did not update. so either i comment out $scope.get_user() in de get_user function and then i can delete a user or i don't comment it out and the loop will update when i add a new user but then the delete function does not work ...

Comment: Just trying to udnerstand code, why are you calling $scope.get_user inside function $scope.get_user is not making it infinite loop? you are calling same function from inside function.

Comment: @MilosMosovsky, because then the list updates

Comment: i added working snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Check my snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('AddUser', ['ngMaterial']);

app.run(['$templateCache',
  function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('popup.tmpl.html', '<md-dialog aria-label="Add or invite a user" ng-app="AddUser">' +
      '<form ng-controller="AppCtrl">' +
      '<md-toolbar>' +
      '<div class="md-toolbar-tools">' +
      '<h2>Add or invite a user</h2>' +
      '<span flex></span>' +
      '<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="closeDialog()">' +
      '<md-icon md-svg-src="images/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>' +
      '</md-button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</md-toolbar>' +
      '<md-dialog-content>' +
      '<div>' +
      '<div layout="" layout-sm="column">' +
      '<md-input-container flex="">' +
      '<label>Enter a name</label>' +
      '<input name="user_email" ng-model="user_name">' +
      '</md-input-container>' +
      '</div>' +

      '<div layout="" layout-sm="column">' +
      '<md-input-container flex="">' +
      '<label>Enter an e-mail</label>' +
      '<input name="user_name" ng-model="user_email">' +
      '</md-input-container>' +
      '</div>' +
      ' </div>' +
      '</md-dialog-content>' +
      '<div class="md-actions" layout="row">' +
      '<md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
      'Cancel' +
      '</md-button>' +
      '<md-button ng-click="save()" name="add_user" class="md-primary">' +
      'Add' +
      '</md-button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</form>' +
      '</md-dialog>');


  }
]);

app.factory('UsersService', ['$q',
  function($q) {

    var service = {};
    service.data = [{
      user_name: 'Stack Overflow',
      id: 1
    }];

    service.get = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      deferred.resolve(service.data);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    service.save = function(data) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      data.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 111);
      service.data.push(data);
      deferred.resolve();
      return deferred.promise;
    }
    service.delete = function(user) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      alert('deleting user ' + user.id);
      var index = service.data.indexOf(user);
      service.data.splice(index, 1);
      deferred.resolve();
      return deferred.promise;

    }
    return service;
  }
]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $mdDialog, UsersService) {
  $scope.userInfo = [];


  function getUsers() {
    UsersService.get().then(function(data) {
      _this.userInfo = data;
    });
  }
  getUsers();

  this.showPopUp = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'popup.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
    })
  };


  this.delete_user = function(user) {
    UsersService.delete(user).then(function() {
      getUsers();

    });
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    var obj = {
      'user_name': $scope.user_name,
      'user_email': $scope.user_email
    };
    UsersService.save(obj).then(function() {
      getUsers();
      $mdDialog.hide();
    });
  }

  function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    }

  }

  var _this = this;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="AddUser">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Test 1 - Add user</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic" />
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as _">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in _.userInfo ">{{user.user_name}} [{{user.id}}]<a href="#" ng-click="_.delete_user(user)"> --> Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="_.showPopUp($event)" flex="" flex-md="100">
    Add a user
  </md-button>
  <!-- <button type="button" id="btnAddUser" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. i will have to go thoroughly through your code. because you write it differently then me and i am still very new to the whole angular concept. Do yo know by any chance what is wrong with my code?

Comment: in my experience, usally this is because de-syncing scope, scope is literally hell , try to learn Controller as syntax (search in google) , thats best design pattern in angular. (Actualy $scope has been removed in angular2 because of this problems, but you ran into this problem very soon :P ) Refreshing $scope inside promises causing problems with sync-ing, i had to rewrite about 60 000 lines of code in old project because of $scope, try to avoid $scope whenever its possible.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. just out of curiosity the code that i have now, is there a solution or a work around that i don't have to implement the new syntax of angular2? the reason i ask this is because my code makes sense to me, yours is a little bit complicated for me ;-)

Comment: I would respond on the POST action from backend with ID , of created entity, and update only $scope.userInfo , and dont call backend, dont get mad now but its stupid pattern to call GET after each action, when you call DELETE you should remove item from scope , and thats all , dont call again GET backend because you dont need to, also on POST action , just respond with full entity (with ID) from backend and just push it to the scope, again skip GET part, you only need GET part when user load screen (to load initial data) everything else is manipulation of scope.

Comment: mmmm ok, i will try to make the necessary changes and hopefully it will work. so if i understand your explanation then i have to make changes in my php and not in app.js? thanks again for all your help