# How to work around a digested cycle with the old angular

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

Via this post ([Angular does not updated loop due to implementation $mdDialog (Material Design)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121071/angular-does-not-updated-loop-due-to-implementation-mddialog-material-design/31125101?noredirect=1#comment50263397_31125101)) yesterday Milos Mosovsky helped me out but he did so with a total rewrite of the code, which i don't completely understand.

So i would like to know how to work a round a digested cycle that occurs i my code. i read somewhere that i should apply "$scope.apply();" but i don't know where exactly in my code.

the situation that i have at the moment is that i had to comment out the following code in the get_user function ($scope.get_user();) otherwise i could not preform a delete but then on the other hand the loop did not update. so either i comment out $scope.get_user() in de get_user function and then i can delete a user or i don't comment it out and the loop will update when i add a new user but then the delete function does not work ...

for the full code of my app.js, html and php check the link in this post (refers back to a post i posted yesterday)

i really hope someone can help me out with this issue well maintaining my current code

Comment: isn't one of the problems that you are creating an loop by calling $scope.get_user() inside the $scope.get_user function itself?

Comment: When outside of a digest loop (check $scope.$$phase for that) you can call $scope.$apply() to propagate changes you made in scope data.

Comment: @Marvin Smit, the reason i do this is other wise the list will not update

Comment: so you keep on loading the user, over and over and over and.....

Comment: @MarvinSmit, how to do this exactly with scope.apply. if you could give a bit of code that would help me greatly. thanks

Comment: if (!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); } is about it.

Comment: this bit of code i would put in the $scope.get_user() function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81940/discussion-between-marvin-smit-and-gy22).